# JModelica and Concurrent Futures

Tags: python, concurrency, modelica, jmodelica

I am using JModelica to optimize a model using IPOPT in the background.

I would like to run many optimizations in parallel. At the moment I am doing
this using the multiprocessing module.

Right now, the code is as follows. It performs a parameter sweep over the
variables `T` and `So` and writes the results to output files named for these
parameters. The output files also contain a list of the parameters used in the
model along with the run results.

```
#!/usr/local/jmodelica/bin/jm_python.sh
import itertools
import multiprocessing
import numpy as np
import time
import sys
import signal
import traceback
import StringIO
import random
import cPickle as pickle

def PrintResToFile(filename,result):
  def StripMX(x):
    return str(x).replace('MX(','').replace(')','')

  varstr = '#Variable Name={name: <10}, Unit={unit: <7}, Val={val: <10}, Col={col:< 5}, Comment="{comment}"\n'

  with open(filename,'w') as fout:
    #Print all variables at the top of the file, along with relevant information
    #about them.
    for var in result.model.getAllVariables():
      if not result.is_variable(var.getName()):
        val = result.initial(var.getName())
        col = -1
      else:
        val = "Varies"
        col = result.get_column(var.getName())

      unit = StripMX(var.getUnit())
      if not unit:
        unit = "X"

      fout.write(varstr.format(
        name    = var.getName(),
        unit    = unit,
        val     = val,
        col     = col,
        comment = StripMX(var.getAttribute('comment'))
      ))

    #Ensure that time variable is printed
    fout.write(varstr.format(
      name    = 'time',
      unit    = 's',
      val     = 'Varies',
      col     = 0,
      comment = 'None'
    ))

    #The data matrix contains only time-varying variables. So fetch all of
    #these, couple them in tuples with their column number, sort by column
    #number, and then extract the name of the variable again. This results in a
    #list of variable names which are guaranteed to be in the same order as the
    #data matrix.
    vkeys_in_order = [(result.get_column(x),x) for x in result.keys() if result.is_variable(x)]
    vkeys_in_order = map(lambda x: x[1], sorted(vkeys_in_order))

    for vk in vkeys_in_order:
      fout.write("{0:>13},".format(vk))
    fout.write("\n")

    sio = StringIO.StringIO()
    np.savetxt(sio, result.data_matrix, delimiter=',', fmt='%13.5f')
    fout.write(sio.getvalue())




def RunModel(params):
  T  = params[0]
  So = params[1]

  try:
    import pyjmi
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)

    #For testing what happens if an error occurs
    # import random
    # if random.randint(0,100)<50:
      # raise "Test Exception"

    op = pyjmi.transfer_optimization_problem("ModelClass", "model.mop")
    op.set('a',        0.20)
    op.set('b',        1.00)
    op.set('f',        0.05)
    op.set('h',        0.05)
    op.set('S0',         So)
    op.set('finalTime',   T)

    # Set options, see: http://www.jmodelica.org/api-docs/usersguide/1.13.0/ch07s06.html
    opt_opts                                   = op.optimize_options()
    opt_opts['n_e']                            = 40
    opt_opts['IPOPT_options']['tol']           = 1e-10
    opt_opts['IPOPT_options']['output_file']   = '/z/err_'+str(T)+'_'+str(So)+'_info.dat'
    opt_opts['IPOPT_options']['linear_solver'] = 'ma27' #See: http://www.coin-or.org/Ipopt/documentation/node50.html

    res = op.optimize(options=opt_opts)

    result_file_name = 'out_'+str(T)+'_'+str(So)+'.dat'
    PrintResToFile(result_file_name, res)

    return (True,(T,So))
  except:
    ex_type, ex, tb = sys.exc_info()
    return (False,(T,So),traceback.extract_tb(tb))

try:
  fstatus = open('status','w')
except:
  print("Could not open status file!")
  sys.exit(-1)

T       = map(float,[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100,110,120,130,140])
So      = np.arange(0.1,30.1,0.1)
tspairs = list(itertools.product(T,So))
random.shuffle(tspairs)

pool  = multiprocessing.Pool()
mapit = pool.imap_unordered(RunModel,tspairs)
pool.close()

completed = 0

while True:
  try:
    res = mapit.next(timeout=2)
    pickle.dump(res,fstatus)
    fstatus.flush()
    completed += 1
    print(res)
    print "{0: >4} of {1: >4} ({2: >4} left)".format(completed,len(tspairs),len(tspairs)-completed)
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pool.terminate()
    pool.join()
    sys.exit(0)
  except multiprocessing.TimeoutError:
    print "{0: >4} of {1: >4} ({2: >4} left)".format(completed,len(tspairs),len(tspairs)-completed)
  except StopIteration:
    break
```

Using the model:

```
optimization ModelClass(objective=-S(finalTime), startTime=0, finalTime=100)
  parameter Real S0 = 2;
  parameter Real F0 = 0;

  parameter Real a = 0.2;
  parameter Real b = 1;
  parameter Real f = 0.05;
  parameter Real h = 0.05;

  output Real F(start=F0, fixed=true, min=0, max=100, unit="kg");
  output Real S(start=S0, fixed=true, min=0, max=100, unit="kg");

  input Real u(min=0, max=1);
equation
  der(F) = u*(a*F+b);
  der(S) = f*F/(1+h*F)-u*(a*F+b);
end ModelClass;
```

Is this safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not safe. `op.optimize()` will store the optimization results with a file name derived from the model name, and then load the results to return the data, so when you try to run several optimizations at once you will get a race condition. To circumvent this, you can provide distinct result file names in `opt_opts['result_file_name']`.

Answer (score 0):

**No.** It does not seem to be safe as of 02015-11-09.

The code above names output files according to the input parameters. The output files also contain the input parameters used to run the model.

With 4 cores two situations arise:

- Occasionally the error `Inconsistent number of lines in the result data.` is raised in the file `/usr/local/jmodelica/Python/pyjmi/common/io.py`.
- Output files show one set of parameters internally but are named for a different set of parameters, which indicates disagreement between the parameters the script thinks it is processing and the parameters that are actually being processed.

With 24 cores:

- The error `The result does not seem to be of a supported format.` is repeatedly raised by `/usr/local/jmodelica/Python/pyjmi/common/io.py`.

Together, this information suggests that intermediate files are being used by JModelica, but that there is overlap in the names of the intermediate files resulting in errors in the best case and incorrect results in the worst case.

One might hypothesize that this is the result of bad random number generation in a `tempfile` function somewhere, but a bug relating to that was [resolved on 02011-11-25](https://bugs.python.org/issue12856). Perhaps the PRNGs are being seeded based on a system clock or a constant and therefore progress in sync?

However, this does not seem to be the case since the following does not produce collisions:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
import tempfile
import os
import collections

from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
  tf = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
  print(tf.name)
  return tf.name

p      = Pool(24)
ret    = p.map(f, range(2000))
counts = collections.Counter(ret)
print(counts)
```